# Fails to perform keys down and hit enter in context menu python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, contextmenu

I want to login to a site. Right-click on one of the links and open in New Tab or New Window.

I have searched earlier here and googled around before posting it here. May be I am doing it wrong

```py
button=browser.find_element_by_link_text('Menus');
action=ActionChains(browser)
action.context_click(button).perform() #--> Till here working fine, Right clicks on Menu
action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN+Keys.ARROW_DOWN+Keys.ENTER).perform() #--> Not Working
```

Comment: Thanks for delaying, it made me more inquisitive and started looking elsewhere. 

I found that using pyautogui.

``` python
import pyautogui

button=browser.find_element_by_link_text('Menus');
action=ActionChains(browser)
action.context_click(button).perform() #--> Till here working fine, Right clicks on Menu
pyautogui.typewrite(['down','enter'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go into that direction as performing context menu clicks will bite you back when you'll be [running your Selenium tests in Parallel Mode](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices)

Instead of opening context menu and clicking I would rather recommend:

1. Extract [`href` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp) from the link
2. Use [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) JavaScript function to open the link in the new tab
3. Use [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wail until number of windows becomes 2
4. [Switch](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) the context to the new tab

Example code:

```
button = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Menus')
href = button.get_attribute("href")
browser.execute_script("window.open('" + href + "')")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
```